# First form normalization in dbsm

Tags: database

I need one explanation how to do 1st normalization form in database.

```
Order(orderID,  customerID, customerName, customerAddress1, customerAddress2, 
customerPostalCode customerCity, customerCountry, customerEmail, customerPhoneNumber, 
customerDOB, customerGender, bankCardNumber, bankCardExpiringDate, billingAddress1, 
billingAddress2, paymentID, paymentDetails, customerCity, orderDateOfOrder,
orderShippingDate, orderPrice, totalPrice, productID, productName, productDescription, 
productQuantity, productDiscount, productsOrdered, shipperID, companyName, 
shipperContact, supplierID, supplierPhone, supplierEmail, suplierPostalCode, 
supplierCompanyName, supplierAddress1, supplierAddress2,  supplierCity)
```

What approach would be good for the first normalization form, the rule should be to eliminate repeating groups, what exactly does it mean by that?

Thanks for helping

Comment: [Demonstrating 1st normal form](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was at your place, I might have used below tables -

```
Table 1 - 
CUSTOMER:

customerID | customerName | customerAddress1 | customerAddress2 | customerPostalCode | customerCity | customerCountry | customerEmail | customerPhoneNumber | customerDOB | customerGender
```

```
Table 2 - 
PAYMENTS:

paymentID | customerID | orderID | bankCardNumber | bankCardExpiringDate | billingAddress1 | billingAddress2 | paymentDetails
```

```
Table 3 - 
PRODUCTS:

productID | productName | productDescription | productQuantity | productDiscount | productsOrdered
```

```
Table 4 -
SHIPMENT:

OrderID | shipperID | companyName | shipperContact | supplierID | supplierPhone | supplierEmail | suplierPostalCode | supplierCompanyName | supplierAddress1 | supplierAddress2 supplierCity
```

```
Table 5 -
ORDER:

CustomerID | orderID | productID | orderDateOfOrder | orderShippingDate | orderPrice | totalPrice
```

This is just a basic idea to implement your business model. You may further discuss this some other expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Think of repeating groups as information that is repeated unnecessarily in each record. In your example, for instance, each order from the same customer would require repeating all the customer information for each order record. The customer information should be "normalized" out into its own "customer" table record rather than including it in the order record.